# Read Each line not reading through entire file

Tags: vb.net, windows

I am using Vb to take a .txt file, parse it, and check for errors. My code works just fine, however, the code does not go through the entire file. It stops, on average, 20 lines shy of the EOF.

I am using the following

```
For Each lines As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(myFile)
```

from here I parse the line and see if it needs any fixes.

Is there something that I'm missing or something that just cant be avoided.

The files that I'm reading in are about 150,000 KB to 230,000 KB and over 2 million lines.

As requested, the following is my code. Warning, I just started using Vb...

```
    Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim root As String = "C:\Users\mschramm\Documents\Agco\WindSensor\Data\filestobecleaned\"
    Dim datafile As String = root & "ES.txt"
    Dim outfile As String = root & "temptry.txt"

    Dim output As System.IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(outfile, False)
    Dim k As UInteger = 0
    Dim fixes As UInteger = 0
    Dim time As ULong = 0
    Dim count As UInteger = 0
    Dim n As UInteger = 0
    Dim LineCount As UInteger = 0
    Dim TimeStep As ULong = 100
    Dim Solar As UInteger = 0

    For Each lines As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(datafile)
        LineCount = LineCount + 1

        'Console.WriteLine(LineCount)

        Dim parsedline As String() = Split(lines, ",")

        If IsNumeric(parsedline(0)) = True And UBound(parsedline) = 8 Then
            'TimeStep = parsedline(0) - time
            Solar = parsedline(1)
            time = parsedline(0)
            output.WriteLine(lines & "    Good Line")
            count = count + 1

        Else

            Dim j As UInteger = 0
            Dim ETX As Integer = 0
            Dim STX As Integer = 0
            Dim datacheck As Boolean = False
            Dim fixedline As String = ""
            Dim newtime As ULong = 0

            For j = 0 To UBound(parsedline)
                Dim a As Char = parsedline(j)
                If a = (Chr(3)) Then ETX = j
                If a = (Chr(2)) Then STX = j
            Next

            j = 0
            If (STX < ETX) And (ETX - STX) = 6 And STX >= 2 Then
                If Len(parsedline(STX + 1)) = 8 And Len(parsedline(STX + 2)) = 8 And Len(parsedline(STX + 3)) = 8 Then
                    Dim g = Len(parsedline(STX - 2))
                    While (j < g) And datacheck = False
                        If IsNumeric(parsedline(STX - 2)) Then
                            If parsedline(STX - 2) - time < 10000 And parsedline(STX - 2) - time > 0 Then
                                newtime = Right(parsedline(STX - 2), Len(parsedline(STX - 2)))
                                Solar = parsedline(STX - 1)
                                'TimeStep = newtime - time
                                fixedline = newtime & "," & parsedline(STX - 1) & "," & parsedline(STX) & "," & parsedline(STX + 1) & "," & parsedline(STX + 2) & "," & parsedline(STX + 3) & "," & parsedline(STX + 4) & "," & parsedline(STX + 5) & "," & parsedline(STX + 6) & "   Fixed Line"
                                datacheck = True
                            Else
                                j = j + 1
                                parsedline(STX - 2) = Right(parsedline(STX - 2), Len(parsedline(STX - 2)) - 1).ToString
                            End If
                        Else
                            j = j + 1
                            parsedline(STX - 2) = Right(parsedline(STX - 2), Len(parsedline(STX - 2)) - 1).ToString
                        End If
                    End While
                End If
            End If

            If (STX < ETX) And (ETX - STX) = 6 And STX = 0 Then
                If Len(parsedline(1)) = 8 And Len(parsedline(2)) = 8 And Len(parsedline(3)) = 8 And Len(parsedline(4)) = 1 And Len(parsedline(5)) = 2 And Len(parsedline(6)) = 3 Then
                    newtime = time + TimeStep
                    fixedline = newtime & "," & Solar & "," & parsedline(STX) & "," & parsedline(STX + 1) & "," & parsedline(STX + 2) & "," & parsedline(STX + 3) & "," & parsedline(STX + 4) & "," & parsedline(STX + 5) & "," & parsedline(STX + 6) & "   Fixed Line Gave Time and Solar"
                    datacheck = True
                End If
            End If

            If newtime < time And newtime > 1000 Then
                Dim badtime As ULong = newtime
                Dim firstdig As ULong = time
                Dim loopcount As UInteger = 0
                While firstdig > 9
                    firstdig = firstdig / 10
                    loopcount = loopcount + 1
                End While
                firstdig = firstdig * (10 ^ loopcount)
                If (firstdig + badtime) > time Then
                    newtime = firstdig + badtime
                    If (newtime - (10 ^ loopcount)) > time Then
                        newtime = newtime - (10 ^ loopcount)
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            If datacheck = True Then
                k = k + 1
                If (newtime > 500) Then
                    output.WriteLine(fixedline)
                    'count = count + 1
                    time = newtime
                End If
            End If

            If datacheck = False Then
                n = n + 1
                If STX >= 0 And ETX > 0 And ETX - STX < 9 Then
                    Console.WriteLine(LineCount)
                    'n = n + 1
                End If
            End If

        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(count & "  Good lines")
    Console.WriteLine(k & "  Lines Corrected")
    Console.WriteLine(LineCount & " Total Lines")
    Console.WriteLine(n & " Lines were thrown out")
    Console.WriteLine(n / LineCount * 100 & "% thrown out")

End Sub
```

End Module

and here is a sample of the data

```
Time: 16:52:18.0
Date: 11/6/2014
Time,Sensor1,U,V,W
544161,219,Q,-001.341,+000.947,+000.140,M,00,17
544284,218,Q,-001.207,+001.074,+000.225,M,00,1C
544361,220,Q,-000.935,+000.898,+000.187,M,00,17
544460,220,Q,-001.299,+001.151,-000.009,M,00,17
```

This is what the last 10 lines look like

```
Q,+001.681,-003.510,-0356154697,236,Q,+000.826,-002.744,-000.559,M,00,19
Q,+000.474,-002.789,-0356155062,234,Q,+000.400,-002.975,+000.438,M,00,1D
Q,+000.813,-002.934,-0356155297,236,Q,+000.146,-002.129,-000.235,M,00,16
Q,+000.494,-002.234,+0356155497,236,Q,+000.681,-001.996,-000.248,M,00,1F
Q,+000.800,-001.999,-0356155697,236,Q,+001.181,-002.883,-000.795,M,00,1A
356156060,233,Q,+000.400,-002.106,+000.251,M,00,18
356156296,235,Q,+000.888,-001.026,+000.442,M,00,10
356156495,236,Q,+000.570,-001.694,+000.589,M,00,13
356156695,236,Q,+001.495,-002.177,-000.035,M,00,15
356157060,234,Q,+000.770,-003.484,-000.161,M,00,14
```

for this file, the code makes it to the 6th to last line.

Comment: Can you add the code sample?

Comment: You will probably need to add a **code** sample, as well as a **file** sample, if you want us to help you.

Comment: How do you know you get ~20 lines from EOF? Do you get an error or are you going by counts? If you get an error, what is it?

Comment: @Mafafu
I receive no error message. I look at the furthest line of the edited file and compare the first columns to see if anything was left out.

Comment: Are you running this from the command line or from Visual Studio? Some possible culprits: 1) you may be getting an exception near the end of the files which you could trap with a `try` block inside your loop. 2) If you're still in the debugger when you see this, try adding an `output.Close()` at the end of the `Main` sub. Its contents might not have been flushed to disk without this.

Comment: @mafafu  
Thank you the output.close() did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mafafu for pointing out the solution.

I never closed the file, so the addition of `output.Close()` fixed everything.

Once again, thank you mafafu.